# Reason of using full recovery model for database

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

I use SQL Server and want to know that what are reasons that we may choose full recovery model?

For example I know that when we want to use `CDC`, or `Mirroring` must set our database recovery mode to full.

**EDIT :**

databases of SharePoint are full recovery mode. Can I change them to simple?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It is safe to change the SharePoint databases (admin, service, and content) recovery model to Simple if you have no need for Full in your environment. Use the same decision making process for the recovery model of SharePoint databases as you would for any other database.

The following TechNet article covers the backup and restore best practices in SharePoint (2010 and 2013):

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg266384(v=office.15).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Some of reason was these:

- CDC (Change data capture)
- Point in Time
- Database Mirroring
- Log shipping
- Create Transaction log backup (for critical data)